# if, elseif, searching, comparison, greater, smaller

Tags: vb.net

I have this code on VB. I get no syntax error but when running and testing the numbers i get "number is not valid" or a wrong answer. Would you please help me what is wrong with this code? Thank you.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    Dim Num As Integer
    Dim str As String
    str = TextBox1.Text
    Num = Integer.Parse(str)


    If Num >= 100 And Num <= 199 Then

        TextBox2.Text = "Basement"

    ElseIf Num >= 200 And Num <= 500 And Num >= 900 Then

        TextBox2.Text = "Main Floor"

    ElseIf Num <= 700 And Num >= 501 And Num >= 750 And Num <= 900 Then

        TextBox2.Text = "Upper Floor"

    ElseIf Num <= 750 And Num >= 700 Then

        TextBox2.Text = "Archives"
    Else
        TextBox2.Text = "Number is not valid"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: VS comes with a debugger which works great to solve this sort of problem.  You should also take the [tour]

Comment: Don't assume you have a valid number in your text box. Use [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: **[Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)**

Comment: `And Num <= 500 And Num >= 900` how can this ever be the case?

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, I really did not check the math part, when I read your comments I got what I have done. Because this is what the professor asked us to do. This is for a small library that shows where are the books when you enter the books' number. So he just confused us with this. I think I have to put only one condition for each if so it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

This is impossible

```
ElseIf Num >= 200 And Num <= 500 And Num >= 900 Then
```

Here you are asking that a number be greater-equal than 200 (ok), lower-equal than 500 (ok) AND greater-equal than 900 (not ok since you already asked for a number lower-equal than 500). A number can't both be lower than 500 and greater than 900.

Without having the requirements, it's hard to know what your if statement should look like. I would suggest you run through your code manually "on paper" or start with one if statement at a time instead of writing all of them.

Comment: also `ElseIf Num <= 700 And Num >= 501 And Num >= 750 And Num <= 900 Then`

Answer (score 2):

I would not mix to many checks in one line as it can get confusing.

Do somthing like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    Dim Num As Integer
    Dim str As String
    str = TextBox1.Text
    Num = Integer.Parse(str)

    If Num >= 100 And Num <= 199 Then
        TextBox2.Text = "Basement"
    ElseIf Num >= 200 And Num <= 500 Then
        TextBox2.Text = "Main Floor"
    ElseIf Num >= 501 And Num <= 700 then
        TextBox2.Text = "Upper Floor"
    ElseIf Num ..... and so on
    Else
        TextBox2.Text = "Number is not valid"
    End If

End Sub
```

Also it's good practice to name your `TextBox` controls and any other controls:

- `textbox1` could be something like `txtfloornumber`
- `textbox2` could be something like `txtfloorname`

This makes coming back to your code later in life easier.